# Problema al renderizar en pug nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pug

Estoy tratando de renderizar el siguiente codigo en pug para que me genere una pagina html:

```
each movie in data
                        tr
                            td #{movie.movie_id}
                            td #{movie.title}
                            td #{movie.release_year}
                            td #{movie.rating}
                            td 
                                form(method="get" action="/editar/#{movie.movie_id}")
                                    input.button.edit(type="submit", value="editar")
                            td 
                                form(method="post" action="/eliminar/#{movie.movie_id}")
                                    input.button.delete(type="button", value="eliminar" onclick="eliminar(this)")
                                    input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="delete")
```

El problema es al renderizar los forms. Por ejemplo en la linea `td #{movie.movie_id}` obtengo el id correctamente, pero cuando trato de hacer lo mismo desde dentro del formulario con la linea `form(method="get" action="/editar/#{movie.movie_id}")` obtengo el html `<form method="get" action="/editar/#{movie.movie_id}">` en vez de `<form method="get" action="/editar/1">`. Es decir no me resuelve `#{movie.movie_id}` sino que lo pinta tal cual.¿Alguien sabe como corregir esto? Me pasa lo mismo en el eliminar. Lo extraño es que en las lineas que no tienen form y solo el td, si lo hace correctamente.

Comment: No conozco **pug** pero se me ocurre saques la variable fuera del literal ej: `action="/editar/"#{movie.movie_id})`

Comment: Eso ya lo intente y me sale `Syntax Error: Unexpected character '#'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución:

Resulta que para `jade` esta sintaxis es correcta:

```
form(method="get" action="/editar/#{movie.movie_id}")
```

pero en `pug` hay que cambiarla por:

```
form(method="get" action=`/editar/${movie.movie_id}`)
```

Lo encontré en la sección [Attribute Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) de la documentación de `pug`.

Comment: Otra opcion: form(method="get" action="/editar/"+movie.movie_id)

Comment: Eso lo probé y no renderiza, solo funciona en `jade` pero no en `pug`

Answer (score 0):

Excelente probé la solución por abrahamhs, y me funcionó correctamente en una etiqueta a en pug

```
a(href=`${link}`  target="_blank")= title
```

Cuando interpolaba el atributo link del objeto en el servidor me daba un error.